# Detect uitextview empty line

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I have two `UITextView` that let the user input some text in the 1st text view and result in some different text in the 2nd textview.

User can input next line in the 1st text view, however I do not wish to generate empty line in the 2nd text view. I wonder how can I detect if there's empty line in the 1st textview and remove those lines?

Thank you.

Result with the character input count error:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

if ([inputTextSection.text rangeOfString:@"\n\n"].location == NSNotFound) return;
NSString *resultStr = [inputTextSection.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n\n" withString:@"\n"];
inputTextSection.text = resultStr;


 int maxChars = 70; //maximum characters
 int charsLeft = maxChars - [inputTextSection.text length];

 if(charsLeft == 0) {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No more characters"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have reached the character limit of %d.",maxChars]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

liveCountTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/70",charsLeft];}
```

Comment: Try some experimenmts with '\n'.

Comment: Have you seen some NSString methods like    [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Comment: @ArpitParekh can you please explain more? how can I imply the code to my case? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should set `delegate` of the first `UITextView`.
2. In the text view delegate implement the method above:

   ```
   - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
   {
       if ([textView.text rangeOfString:@"\n\n"].location == NSNotFound) return;
       NSString *resultStr = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n\n" withString:@"\n"];
       textView.text = resultStr;
   }
   ```

That will remove all empty lines.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thanks a lot! However, I'm sorry! I don't have enough reputation for vote for your answer.

Comment: I have a new problem about the code when I'm implementing the character count in here. The script can either do the counting or do this clear empty line method. I wonder how should the code be written to combine the two methods? Please take a look at my edited question, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hm. What works wrong? By the way replace `if(charsLeft == 0)` with `if(charsLeft <= 0)`

Comment: I can only make either one parameter works. In the script above, `liveCountTextView.text` works, but then your script doesnt work. If I just use your script, it works perfectly.

Comment: @zeropt7 At the beginning of your method add this line: `if (textView != inputTextSection) return;`